# Remove indent from figure caption when using arsclassica option for classicthesis

Tags: captions, classicthesis, arsclassica

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{text text text text text text text text text tex text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex text text text text text text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I remove the white space below the figure title?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `arsclassica` option eventually does `\captionsetup{format=hang}`. You can switch back to `format=plain` after loading `classicthesis`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}
\captionsetup{format=plain} % % % % % %  here
\usepackage{graphicx}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{text text text text text text text text text tex text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex text text text text text text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```